# Calculate total based on Key Press Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have 3 textbox

Quantity
Rate
Total

I want a key press event that when i type any amount in Rate then the total should be calculated.I have a option of text change Event but that is fired when i leave the textbox. I want to have Key press event of textbox. I have following code.

```
$('#<%=txtRate.ClientID %>').keypress(function (event) {

            alert($('#<%=txtRate.ClientID %>').val());

 });
```

Problem i am facing is when i get the alert it does not show me the current pressed value.
means if i have value in textbox 1 and if i press 2 then it will just alert me 1 as the event fires when i click. so the present value is not recorded.

Comment: Try `.keyup()` instead of `.keypress()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To immediately detect the current click one must use the `.keyup()` event

Answer (score 0):

If you using latest jquery lib then use `.on` otherwise `.live` would be better.

```
$('input').on('keyup', function(e) {
 delayKeyUp(function(){set_payment()}, 350); // delay of 350 ms.
 return false;
});

var delayKeyUp = (function(){
        var timer = 0;
        return function(callback, ms){
            clearTimeout (timer);
            timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
        };
    })();
```